# Why "bu" in burial is pronounced as "be" in bed?

Tags: pronunciation

Why "bu" in burial is not pronounced as "bu" in burrow? Is there a rule behind it, or it's just random?

Comment: Oh, in my accent it does rhyme with burrow...

Comment: Note that for most Americans, *burial* does **not** have the /ɛ/ vowel of DRESS but rather the /e/ vowel of FACE.

Comment: [Here](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/31999/42179)'s a similar/related question for _busy_.

Comment: @tchrist: For most Americans, the /ɛ/ vowel of DRESS and the /e/ of FACE are merged when they come before an /r/, and can be pronounced with either one, or something in between, depending on your dialect. I certainly pronounce *bury* with the vowel of DRESS. [Oxford American Dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/about/pronunciation_american_english) agrees with me (but they're based in England; what do they know?)

Comment: Never make assumptions about English pronunciation. Someone will always prove you wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ***Word History**:* Why does *bury* rhyme with *berry* and not with *jury*? The answer goes back to early English times. The late Old English form of the verb *bury* was *byrgan*, pronounced approximately (bür′yən). During Middle English times this (ü) sound changed, but with different results in different regions of England: to (o͝o) as in *put* in the Midlands, to (ĭ) as in *pit* in southern England, or to (ĕ) as in *pet* in southeast England. London is located in the East Midlands, but because of its central location and its status as the capital, its East Midlands dialect was influenced by southern (Saxon) and southeastern (Kentish) dialects. The normal East Midlands development of (ü) was (o͝o), spelled *u*. Because scribes from the East Midlands pronounced the word with this vowel they tended to spell the word with a *u*, and this spelling became standard when spellings were fixed after the introduction of printing. The word's pronunciation, however, is southeastern. *Bury* is the only word in Modern English with a Midlands spelling and a southeastern pronunciation. Similarly, the word *busy*, from Old English *bysig*, *bisig*, and its verb *bysgian*, *bisgian*, "to employ," is spelled with the East Midlands dialect *u*, but pronounced with the southern (Saxon) development of (ü), (ĭ)

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bury

Comment: "London is located in the East Midlands," I don't know if that was true in Middle English times (though I doubt the term East Midlands even existed then - more likely it was called Mercia) but it certainly isn't true now. London is sandwiched between the South East, and the East of England (often referred to by its older name of East Anglia, and not the same as the East Midlands region) See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regions_of_England for a map.

Comment: @alephzero You raise a seemingly fair point. I'm merely referencing in this answer and I'm not too confident about correcting it.

Comment: @alephzero: After the Middle English period, London English became heavily influenced by East Anglian dialect (notably in the use of <i>-(e)s</i> instead of <i>-eth</i>, but when /y/ was shifting to other vowels that had not yet happened.